# Enumerating a subset of paths in a sequential probability tree in R

Tags: r, probability

To illustrate the problem, let us define the following matrix (where NA indicates that the option is unavailable in period t)

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(NA, 4, 4, dimnames = list(paste0("t=", seq_len(4)), LETTERS[seq_len(4)]))
x[lower.tri(x, diag = TRUE)] <- rnorm(10)
```

Which gives a matrix that looks like this:

```
              A           B          C         D
t=1  0.91897737          NA         NA        NA
t=2  0.78213630  0.61982575         NA        NA
t=3  0.07456498 -0.05612874 -1.4707524        NA
t=4 -1.98935170 -0.15579551 -0.4781501 0.4179416
```

The goal is to calculate the probability that each value is the highest in each time period $t$, however, the values are conditional on the values in the previous periods. For example, in moving from period `t=2` to `t=3` and the assumption that `A` is the highest, `A` is only compared to `C` and not `B` because in `t=2` it is assumed to be higher. We can structure the problem as a tree like this:

[image]

So for `t=1` the probability is 1, for `t=2` we calculate 2 probabilities from 1 grouping, in `t=3` we calculate 4 probabilities from 2 groupings (note how one option is eliminated from the comparison because of the sequential dependence and inherent assumption that it was not the highest in `t-1`) and in `t=4`, we calculate 8 probabilities from 4 groupings. The final probabilities then are product over the probabilities in each `t` making up the 8 paths. In the real problem, `t` gets large and manually identifying these groupings becomes infeasible.

I've been trying to come up with a clever way of identifying these paths and calculate the probabilities. One idea was to use a set of "masking matrices" for each possible pattern. That way I could simply multiply the masking matrix and perform row operations. However, I could not find a robust way to populate the different masking matrices as the the number of levels increased.

For example, assume the pattern of choosing `A` in all periods leading up to the final period can be described by the following masking matrix:

```
mask <- matrix(c(
1, NA, NA, NA,
1, 1,  NA, NA,
1, NA, 1,  NA,
1, NA, NA, 1
), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(paste0("t=", seq_len(4)), LETTERS[seq_len(4)]))
```

which looks like this (1 of the 4 possible comparisons in this case):

```
    A  B  C  D
t=1 1 NA NA NA
t=2 1  1 NA NA
t=3 1 NA  1 NA
t=4 1 NA NA  1
```

And we can calculate the probabilities in each period like this (all rows sum to one as they should):

```
exp_x <- exp(x * mask)
sum_exp_x <- rowSums(exp_x, na.rm = TRUE)
pr_x <- exp_x / sum_exp_x
```

```
             A         B         C         D
t=1 1.00000000        NA        NA        NA
t=2 0.54048879 0.4595112        NA        NA
t=3 0.82423638        NA 0.1757636        NA
t=4 0.08261824        NA        NA 0.9173818
```

Is there a clever way of doing this for all possible paths as `t`grows? Or a good way of populating a set of masking matrices to loop over? I'm trying to avoid the problem growing out of hand. Is it possible that complete path enumeration and elimination is a better option, i.e. faster and more robust? Any help, ideas and pointers are helpful.

Comment: So only two options are compared for each grouping at a time? In other word, Is it possible that your option-period matrix is non-triangular?

Comment: The option period matrix `x` will always be a lower-triangular matrix (like a tree). Effectively, one option is added each period `t` and we know in advance how many periods there will be, here `T=4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
find_path <- function(nperiods, opts = LETTERS[seq_len(period)]) {
  stopifnot(length(opts) == nperiods)
  out <- matrix(nrow = 2 ^ (nperiods - 1L), ncol = nperiods)
  r <- 1L
  recur_ <- function(period, branch, outcome) {
    if (period > length(branch)) {
      out[r, ] <<- opts[branch]
      r <<- r + 1L
      return(NULL)
    }
    for (i in c(outcome, period)) {
      branch[[period]] <- i
      recur_(period + 1L, branch, i)
    }
  }
  recur_(1L, integer(nperiods), NULL)
  out
}

calc_prob <- function(mat) {
  ps <- dimnames(mat)[[1L]]; if (is.null(ps)) ps <- seq_len(nrow(mat))
  ops <- dimnames(mat)[[2L]]; if (is.null(ops)) ops <- seq_len(ncol(mat))
  paths <- find_path(nrow(mat), ops)
  out <- vapply(seq_len(ncol(paths))[-1L], function(i) {
    comp <- ops[[i]]
    comp <- ifelse(paths[, i] == comp, paths[, i - 1L], comp)
    x <- exp(mat[i, paths[, i]])
    y <- exp(mat[i, comp])
    x / (x + y)
  }, numeric(nrow(paths)))
  dimnames(out) <- NULL; out <- cbind(1, out)
  dimnames(out)[[2L]] <- dimnames(paths)[[2L]] <- ps
  list(paths = paths, probs = out)
}
```

Output

```
> calc_prob(x) # x is the same lower-triangular matrix as shown in your example.

$paths
     t=1 t=2 t=3 t=4
[1,] "A" "A" "A" "A"
[2,] "A" "A" "A" "D"
[3,] "A" "A" "C" "C"
[4,] "A" "A" "C" "D"
[5,] "A" "B" "B" "B"
[6,] "A" "B" "B" "D"
[7,] "A" "B" "C" "C"
[8,] "A" "B" "C" "D"

$probs
     t=1       t=2       t=3        t=4
[1,]   1 0.5404888 0.8242364 0.08261823
[2,]   1 0.5404888 0.8242364 0.91738177
[3,]   1 0.5404888 0.1757636 0.28985432
[4,]   1 0.5404888 0.1757636 0.71014568
[5,]   1 0.4595112 0.8044942 0.36037495
[6,]   1 0.4595112 0.8044942 0.63962505
[7,]   1 0.4595112 0.1955058 0.28985432
[8,]   1 0.4595112 0.1955058 0.71014568
```

The variable `paths` gives you all the possible outcomes for each period *t*; `probs` tells you the probability of a corresponding outcome. **However**, note that such a probability tree grows exponentially as the number of periods increases. The equation is

[image]

where *N* is the number of all possible paths at period *t*. For just 20 periods, you will have 524288 different paths. If the number of periods goes to 30, you will have 536870912 different paths, and R just cannot handle that amount of computations. I do suggest you reconsider your expected outputs. Are you running a simulation with some other constraints than just the time dependence so that we can further trim off some unnecessary paths? Or maybe you only need some summary statistics like the expected value so that we don't have to generate all possible paths? There must be a better way than just using a brute-force approach like this.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am after. I have tried to think about how I can reduce the problem, but I haven't spotted anything yet that will allow me to eliminate more paths. The good thing is that the number of periods is unlikely to exceed 10.